# Whatsmydns shows internal ip for class c whereas for class b it doesnt

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, internal-dns, private-ip

I have a VMWare infrastructure and inside that 2 environments named A and B. "A" has its DNS in the server "D" whereas B has its DNS within itself. The scenario is as given below:

A has domain associated like `bdweb01.lp.rmplc.net` and has its DNS in server D.

- All the A records are inside the server D.

B has domain associated like `int.books.rmlp.com` and has its DNS server within its environment.

- All the A records are inside its own environment DNS server.
- A nameserver record has been created inside the DNS domain "B" in Server D. Which means all the A records required for this environment is contained with in this domain (int.books.rmlp.com) itself. In the server named D, there contains NS record for int.books.rmlp.com so that the requests gets forwarded to the DNS Server of B environment.

Now about the IP's used:

- A environment has the IP's in the range of 192.168.x.x
- B environment has the IP's in the range of 172.28.x.x

Which means both have private IP's.

My Issue:

When I use https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check the IP of a site (eg: `browse.bdweb01.lp.rmplc.net`), it clearly shows the associated IP of this domain. At the same time when I check the IP of a site hosted in my B environment (eg: `browse.int.books.rmlp.com`), it doesn't tell me any IP.

1. Though we use two different classes in the environments, both remains to be the private IP addresses. Then why C Class IP is getting displayed whereas not B Class?
2. I don't think sites in environment A has natted IP's since I recieve the exact internal IP's when checked with whatsmydns. So, how does this work, whereas the other don't?
3. Is there anything that I would need to do, so that I could get the same result in site hosted in environment B also?

Any quick suggestions or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please, seriously consider un-redacting the domain names in this question.  So often these problems come down to a DNS misconfiguration, and those are impossible to diagnose without knowing the domain names involved.

Comment: @MadHatter: Does that mean you require site address which I am checking?

Comment: I mean don't use `pqr.net` and `xyz.com` in the question; use the real fully-qualified domain names in each case.

Comment: @MadHatter: I just gave you an example. Just to make you understand what my current scenario is. Do you want me to add the results of whatsmydns for both environments?

Comment: Not particularly.  I just want you to tell us what the real fully-qualified domain names are; once you've done that, we can try our own tests.  If this question is a theoretical one, and isn't about a specific concrete problem, please say so.

Comment: @MadHatter:Edited..

Comment: OK, thanks.  You only put the real hostnames in in certain places, so I've tried to make it consistent and fix the formatting up.  Can you confirm that the question as it now appears is still an accurate description of the problem?

Comment: *I cringe whenever I see "Class C" and "Class B"*

Comment: @MadHatter: Yeah, except the sites mentioned. The sites would be different. For example sitename.bdweb01.lp.rmplc.net and sitename.int.books.rmlp.com

Comment: Sorry, **what**?  Are you saying that the domains, and fully-qualified hostnames, you put in the question are **still not the real ones**?  Please, **stop using examples** and **put the real data in the question**.

Comment: @MadHatter: Edited again for your easy understanding. Edited on the sitename part.

Comment: OK, grand.  Now you say above that "*a nameserver record has been created inside the DNS domain "B"*", but I see no such delegation inside `rmlp.com`, neither for the subzone `books.rmlp.com`, nor for `int.books.rmlp.com`.  Could you edit the relevant NS records that you think you're advertising, and their corresponding A records, into your question?  At the moment this just looks like faulty delegation rather than having anything to do with the "*class*" (point taken, ewwhite) of the IP addresses in question.

Comment: @MadHatter:Done. Edited in 2nd point of "B has domain associated". Is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you have delegated the subzone `int.books.rmlp.com` on the authoritative nameserver for both `rmplc.net` and `rmlp.com`, which is `ns0.ifl.net.`.  But I don't think this is so:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns int.books.rmlp.com @ns0.ifl.net.

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-15.P2.fc20 <<>> ns int.books.rmlp.com @ns0.ifl.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23323
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
```

Until you fix this delegation, this isn't going to work; the issue has nothing to do with whether the eventual host A records are in some particular portion of RFC1918 address space.

Comment: Are you saying to remove this ns record and add A records directly to this DNS server?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that you may think you've added those `NS` records, but for some reason they're not being served, and that will break everything.

Comment: OK.. I will have a look now.. Thanks for the quick reply..